# Booting straight into Windows, no Grub in BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, uefi, grub-legacy

i probably f*cked up. Yesterday i decided to install Kali Linux along with the pre-installed Windows 10 of my Ideapad 100. One small problem i had though was that i had to change between the "UEFI" and the "Legacy Support" boot modes on the BIOS in order to boot into Windows or Linux. If i chose UEFI the pc booted straight into Windows without Grub appearing, if i chose Legacy support Grub would appear and Kali would boot normally, Windows on the other hand wouldn't boot cause Windows boot manager wasn't working. So i made a live USB of boot-repair-disk and started fiddling around with it. I tried the recommended repair thing, tweaked some advanced settings and followed this guide: https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair to try and repair it myself. Had no luck with any of these and now Kali Linux won't even show up on the Legacy list, so it's pretty much impossible to boot into it right now. Windows boot manager works great as it is on the top of the EFI list. Also fast boot is disabled.

Comment: My experience from working with Windows is that you do not want to ever switch an install from UEFI to Legacy weird bugs happen. Do you have the Kali live installer?

Comment: Yes, i do.......

Comment: Turn off CSM/Legacy boot and boot the installer in UEFI mode. Boot Kali installer in live mode. Open a terminal and then you can fix the boot loader.

Comment: The USB wont boot in UEFI mode it needs Legacy support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of two things happened here:

1. The firmware isn't honoring the update to the EFI boot order.  A handful of systems which supposedly implement UEFI (especially very early ones) don't actually implement the boot manager specification properly, and will refuse to boot anything except `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` (the name of the Windows boot loader) if that file exists on the boot device.  Fixing this is non-trivial, as it requires some creative renaming to avoid Windows messing things up, and any upgrade of Windows will undo whatever you do to fix it.  If this is the case, I highly recommend getting a different system, as the vendors who have done this are somewhat notorious for making stupid choices in firmware that make life very difficult for anyone not using Windows.

or:

2. You booted Windows after installing Linux, and Windows re-synced the EFI variables that control boot order with it's internal boot order settings.  You'll have to update the boot manager setting in Windows with bcdedit to fix this (and will need to do so again each time you upgrade Windows).  [This](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/) page covers how to fix it, but the advice is for Ubuntu, and the path to GRUB for Kali is probably different.  You can use the advice [here](https://superuser.com/questions/965751/how-to-access-efi-partition-on-windows-10) to access the EFI system partition from Windows to figure out where `grub.efi` is, and use that path in the `bcdedit` command.